# How to Set dot on specific date on calendar in android

Tags: java, android, import, kotlin

This is code show event on click date but not visible DOT on Event date i have try to do but nothing goes to happened.

```
package com.example.mis_internee.mycalentest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView;
import com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.domain.Event;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.graphics.Color.RED;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CompactCalendarView compactCalendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM- yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(null);

        compactCalendar = (CompactCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
        compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);
        compactCalendar.setEventIndicatorStyle(Color.BLACK);
        compactCalendar.setCurrentDayBackgroundColor(RED);
        compactCalendar.getEvents(3223213);

        //Set an event for Teachers' Professional Day 2016 which is 21st of October

        Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLACK, 1477040400000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);

        compactCalendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                if (dateClicked.toString().compareTo("Fri Jan 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018") == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Teachers' Professional Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Events Planned for that day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {
                actionBar.setTitle(dateFormatMonth.format(firstDayOfNewMonth));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: which date you are checking?

Comment: Fri Jan 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting timestamp `1477040400000L` here

```
Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLACK, 1477040400000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);
```

Timestamp `1477040400000L` is `Friday, 21 October 2016 09:00:00 GMT +5:30`
so check on that date

if you want to set `Fri Jan 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018` set

```
Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLACK,1516924800000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell How to convert calendar Date into milliseconds??

Comment: i am using compactCalendarView , how can i get date on click on Calendar date? e,g, if i click on 26 date it toast 26-01-2018. in simple calendarView it is done with OnDatechangelist... but here there is no suggestion.

Comment: did you try compactCalendarView.setListener()
if not then check documentation ...